# Import a library that is not a module within Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to import a library that is not a module according to Typescript. I'm trying to import saveSvgAsPng. I've also tried to create a definition but had no luck.

https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng/blob/gh-pages/saveSvgAsPng.js

I did find some types, and I tried manually adding them, but I still get a not a module error. https://github.com/martianov/typed-save-svg-as-png

Answer (score 0):

You can put the declarations you found under a `declarations` folder in your project and make the compiler to read those typings too by configuring the `typeRoots` at your `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions`:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./declarations"
]
```

More info on this here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

---

### Update

Apparently the typing isn't declaring the module.
On the typing you downloaded, wrap everything that is exported by the module with:

```
declare module 'package-name' {
...
```